# Replying in Chat is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, reply

When clicking on the reply button on a message in chat, nothing happens. Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

I like being able to reply to people. Can I please have it back? Chrome 38.0.2125.111 on OS X 10.10

Answer (score 13):

Yep, sorry about that. The fix is already being built out, should be back in a minute. (On the plus side, the @mention autocompleter now works in the mobile version).

Comment: Yay, autocomplete on mobile! Thanks for making mobile chat be not *quite* as horrible.